# Is stable ordinals in non-well-founded model the same as well founded models?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, ordinal-numbers, constructibility

Let $BST$ be the axiom system $KP$ - $\Delta_0$ collection. For an ordinal $\alpha$, we say that $\alpha$ is $\varphi$-$\Sigma_n$-stable, if there is a $\beta>\alpha$ satisfies the formula $φ$ such that $L_\alpha$ is a $\Sigma_n$ elementary submodel of $L_\beta$.

Question: Is the least ordinal $\alpha$ that is a (true)-$\Sigma_2$-stable ordinal in some end extension $M$ of $L_{\alpha+1}$ that satisfies $BST$, also the least (true)-$\Sigma_2$-stable ordinal? What if (true)-$\Sigma_2$-stable is changed to (it's an admissible ordinal)-$\Sigma_1$-stable?

Note: After some reading, I'm sure that the answer of the second question is yes. If $\alpha$ is next admissible stable in $M$, then the $L_{\alpha^+}$ of $M$ (say it's $N$) is an admissible set including $\alpha$. It's not hard to prove that for any recursive function $f$ with parameters in $L_\alpha$, $f(\alpha)=(f(\alpha))^N$, so $\alpha$ is stable to any $\alpha$-recursive ordinal, so it is $\Pi^1_1$ reflecting or $\Sigma^1_1$ reflecting.

However I still don't know the answer of the first question.

Comment: Let me point out that the standard definition of a stable ordinal is an ordinal $\alpha$ satisfying $L_\alpha\prec_{\Sigma_1} L$.

Comment: @HanulJeon What about the other side?

Comment: I cannot see how to produce externally well-founded models from possibly illfounded $M$, so I have to retract my previous claim..

Comment: About "$\alpha$ is stable to any $\alpha$-recursive ordinal, so it is $\Pi_1^1$-reflecting or $\Sigma_1^1$-reflecting", how is the case that $\alpha$ is the least $\Sigma_1^1$-reflecting ordinal ruled out, in which case $\alpha$ would be too large?

Comment: @C7X "the least"

Answer (score 1):

Answer for the first question: the answer is no. Let $\alpha<_{\Sigma_n}\beta$ hold iff $L_\alpha\prec_{\Sigma_n}L_\beta$.
Assume $\alpha$ is the least ordinal such that $\alpha<_{\Sigma_2}\beta$ for some beta.
Now $\alpha$ is +1 stable, so it is a limit of admissible ordinals. This is a $\Pi_2$ property, so $\beta$ is also a limit of admissible ordinals, in particular, $\alpha^++1<\beta$, so $\alpha<_{\Sigma_1}\alpha^++1$.

Assume $\varphi$ is the sentence (on $L_\alpha$) "there are two subsets $M,E$ of $L_\alpha$ such that $\{(x,0)|x\in L_\alpha\}\subset M$ (and it should represent the $L_α$ in model $M$), $E$ is a 2-ary relation of $M$, and the model $(M,E)$ satisfies KP, and $\alpha$ is $\Sigma_2$ stable to a larger ordinal in $M$". $\varphi$ is $\Sigma^1_1$ and true on $L_\alpha$. By theorem 6.2 of Richter and Aczel's paper "[Inductive Definitions and Reflecting Properties of Admissible Ordinals](https://www.duo.uio.no/handle/10852/44063)", $\varphi$ on $L_\alpha$ is (uniformly) equivalent to a $\Pi_1$ formula $\varphi^+(L_\alpha)$ on $L_{\alpha^+}$.

Now from $\alpha<_{\Sigma_1}\alpha^++1$, there is an ordinal $\alpha'<\alpha$ such that $\varphi^+(L_{\alpha'})$ is true on $L_{\alpha'^+}$, so $\varphi$ is true on $L_{\alpha'}$.